# Is there any way in react to Blend text color with image?

Tags: reactjs, gsap, framer-motion

[image: This is the sample image]

Background images are floating on the page according to mouse movement. What i want is that whenever there is an image behind/above the text the color of that specific portion of text get's change similar to given image.

I had tried multiple libraries like Frame-motion, GSAP but I am unable find the solution. If there is kindly let me know.

Comment: You could try modifying your text's fill color and setting it to transparent. Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color

Comment: I think you want [blend modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

Comment: No i had tried blend modes but it didn't worked for me.